# Including Rails time helpers in a non-Rails Ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I primarily use Rails to develop in and I love the `1.hour.from_now`, `34.minutes`, and `24.megabytes` helpers that Rails has built into it. However right now I am building just a Ruby application having these helpers would be nice. Is it possible to just get these helpers in a Ruby application without having to bring in the whole Rails framework?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These methods come from [ActiveSupport's core extensions](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext) (specifically ones on Integer & Numeric), so you can just require them:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'
```

Or if you want all core extensions ActiveSupport provides:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

Or if you want all of ActiveSupport (core extensions included):

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

Of course you have to ensure the [`activesupport` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) is installed.